# Getting HTML markup in a string compiled

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to give a HTML element a markup but it outputs in a string.

My code:

```
var inputString = tweet.text;
var findme = screen_name;
tweet.text = inputString.replace(screen_name, "<span class='searched'>" + screen_name + "</span>")
```

Comment: Did you try converting the ankle bracket to entity references?    &lt;span class='searched'&gt;" + screen_name + "&lt;/span&gt;"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.innerHTML
```

.replace outputs strings, not html

**EDIT**

```
var inputString = tweet.text;
var findme = screen_name;
tweet.text = inputString.replace(screen_name, "<span class='searched'>" + screen_name + "</span>")
SomeHTMLObject.innerHTML=tweet.text;
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't clarify it enough: tweet = an object. Tweet.text is the string.

Comment: .replace outputs string so you have to "rewrite" your object

Answer (score 0):

You're likely experiencing this issue because you're setting the string on the UI as *text*, not *HTML*. Elements have an `innerHTML` property which will create child elements if necessary.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z4LL4dcx/)

```
var inputString = "Hello Daniel!";
var findme = "Daniel";
var replacedString = inputString.replace(findme, "<span class='searched'>" +
                                                 findme + "</span>");
document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = replacedString;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out the solution myself:

In the HTML page, you can should use HTML-escape. So you have to use `{{{ variable }}}` instead of `{{ variable }}`

Simple solution, should have thought about that..